# Is there a CSS-only solution to creating a scrollable table body that is full width?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind, I am having trouble creating a table with a scrollable body that spans the full width. Currently the way I'm doing it is by setting the `tbody` to `display: block` but by doing that the `tbody` isn't the full width. How can I go about making it full width? I want the table body to be scrollable separately from the rest of the page.

[Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2eJggerfCg?layout=horizontal)

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to show some code here.

Answer (score 0):

After removing block class from the tbody and adding

```
<thead class="sticky top-0">
```

You get a separate scroll for your body of your table
[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/fEuHRNSeIq?layout=horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-auto` class to your table.